# Google maps URL scheme to search for multiple places using coordinates

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, url-scheme

I am trying to launch the google maps app from my iOS/Android app in respective mobiles.

URLs to launch the app : comgooglemaps://?q=lat+long
But I need to know if I can pass multiple location coordinates so that multiple pins would appear in the google maps app after launching.

I can find URL scheme for directions and single location to launch the app, multiple locations for static map . But I couldn't find any references in the web for URL schemes to have multiple location coordinates.

Can anyone please help me  ?

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme) there is no parameter for that. Also the maps-URL does not have a parameter for that as you can see [here](http://asnsblues.blogspot.de/2011/11/google-maps-query-string-parameters.html). Maybe an embedded map can be a solution for you as the static maps API has a parameter for this [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Markers).

Comment: Are you certain of that? Can you confirm this? Is there any explicit official information stating that we can't do this? Or is it just asserted from the lack of documentation?

Comment: I linked the official documentation. Also the links working for maps do not work in the maps-URL. It would be strange that google uses different parameters nowhere documented, but you are right without writing a bot to test you can not be certain that there is not a hidden functionality.